# set 1 as a value in database codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

hi i want to se 1 or zero in data base. i made a function in admin_model but its not updating in datebase.

this is admin controler.

```
 function user_ban($id){
        $fb_ban = $this->admin_model->ban_user($id);
        redirect('admin/reportedUsers');
        exit;
    }
```

this is admin_model

```
 public function ban_user($id){
            $this->db->set('ip_baned', 1);
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->update('users');
        }
```

here is my html part where button is sending id and calling function as well.

```
<a style="text-decoration: underline;" href="<?php echo base_url("admin/user_ban/".$users['id']); ?>"><span class='btn btn-success btn-xs' title="Click to Ban">Ban User</span></a>
```

same code is working on other page perfectly.

Comment: try with `$this->db->update('users',array('ip_baned',1));` ok, if its working on other pages than `echo $id;` chk this in your controller what value are u getting.

Comment: your passing uri segment not parameter to the controller function you should access id like this $id=$this->uri->segment(3);

Comment: checked. passing id in controller and in model as well.

Comment: where from your passing $id parameter to the user_ban function ?

Comment: hammad, did u test?

Comment: what is the error when you acces the link?

Comment: thanks for suggestion n help. later i found function were working but i was getting wrong id thats why i couldnt get exect result that time but its fine now thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use below method to execute

```
$this->db->set('ip_baned', '1', FALSE);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('users');
```